# How to redirect JVM output without tear up output from the application?

Tags: java, python, linux, jvm

Recently I am writing some micro-benchmark code, so I have to print out the JVM behaviors along with my benchmark information. I use

```
-XX:+PrintCompilation
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

and other options to get the JVM status. For benchmark information, I simply use `System.out.print()` method. Because I need to know the order of the message I printed and the JVM output.

I can get good result when I just print them out in the console, although the JVM output sometimes tear my messages up, but since they are in different threads, it is understandable and acceptable.

When I need to do some batch benchmarks, I'd like to ***`redirect the output into a file`*** with `pipe (> in Linux system)`, and use python to get the result from the file and analyse it.

Here is the problem:

**`The JVM output always overlapped with the messages I printed in the Java application.`** It ruined the completion of the messages.

Any idea how to deal with this situation? I need **`both the JVM output and application output in the same place in order to preserve the sequence because it is important. And they do not overlap on each other so I don't lose anything.`**

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest taking a slight detour and looking at using Java Instrumentation APIs - use (write) a simple **Java Agent** to do this. From your benchmarking perspective, this will give you far more power as well. You could use your Java Agent to log everything (and hence there would be no contention between different logger threads).

You can read more at http://www.javabeat.net/2012/06/introduction-to-java-agents/ or http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/24/add-logging-at-class-load-time-with-instrumentation.html

Comment: Good idea, I've tried to redirect the stdout and stderr in the agent, I can redirect the output from my java code, but the JVM output is not redirected. And the method introduced in the article you mentioned -- modify the byte code when load the class, I have to know what the JVM invoked when it output the information, then maybe I can modify it, but I don't have that kind of information, do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Try using `System.out.println()` instead of `System.out.print()`.
`System.out.println()` forces a stream flush inside the syncronized section and at least your output won't be as mixed.

Answer (score 5):

Use Log4J or message-driven logging framework versus `System.out.println()`.

Log4J uses a message event-model that guarantees ordering of messages.
Further, various 'appenders' can be used to log to a database or other output/file, allowing for separation by Java package and other attributes so the data are not mixed.

Also, along these lines, consider using a high-performance timer and/or do not attempt to measure very short (millisecond) events. The reason is that a call to `System.currentTimeMillis()` will just in turn call the operating system clock. On every OS there is some 'clock drift' and caching that goes on such that the underlying system function may return the same value, resulting in +/- 30 ms offsets in the actual time. To remedy this or increase accuracy, group the functions being measured into a large enough sample size and then divide by the number of iterations.

For example, perform 10K operations that average 1-2 milliseconds as one measured operation. Then divide by 10K to get time-per-operation.

Otherwise, again, a high-performance timer would be necessary.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. Log4J does not help with the HotSpot diagnostics logs, or the problem of interleaving them in the same file as the application output in a way that reflects their temporal relationships.

Comment: HotSpot diagnostics were not mentioned in the question. The question was how to preserve logging sequence without overlap and the solution is certainly one way to do it.

Comment: The question (when I read it, it has been edited) mentions HotSpot diagnostics, like -XX:+PrintCompilation, and the need to order them correctly with other logging, in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

Directly logging via System.out.print/println is considered poor practice.

Why?

1. It's not 'thread safe'. Logging from multiple threads results in garbled text
2. It's inflexible because it's hard-coded and not configured.
3. It is inflexible because you can't specify the level of detail you would like to see in the log (e.g. detailed tracing/specific debugging logic/app warnings/app error handling/app fatal errors).  You always get the lot and need to comment many lines of code to avoid logging overload.
4. It is inflexible because you can't specify which packages/classes you are or aren't interested in - again you always get the lot and need to comment many lines for anything simpler & more specific
5. It is inflexible because you cant redirect logs to database tables & columns, files, email, message systems, SMS alerts, etc
6. It is inflexible because you can't stream different log levels / packages or classes to different logging destinations.  Also you can't configure it to log to the same destination or a different destination as the app server and it's JVM
7. It's slow when you have thousands / millions of lines being logged to physical disk

In 2000, Log4J was introduced.
It addresses all of these issues and has been more-or-less the standard solution ever since.  While there are some latest & greatest logging tools that attempt to go beyond Log4J, you can still get powerful, flexible results with Log4J.  If you switch all your System.out.print calls to Log4J, then your quoted problem and many others will dissapear.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Answer (score 2):

For `-XX:+PrintCompilation`, you could use `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogCompilation` flags instead to get a "verbose" output in separate "hotspot.log" file. This file is in XML format and contains both the information from `-XX:+PrintCompilation` and the cause of such compilations. The file path can be changed via `-XX:LogFile=<new_hotspot_log>`. Reference: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/LogCompilation+overview

For `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`, you could use `-Xloggc:<gc_log>` to redirect the GC output to the specified file. Reference: `java -X`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try the following. This is more of a hack and would require some tinkering. But mastering this approach would probably pay off in a long run. Especially, if you do a lot of benchmarking.

Having said that I am positive that HS (nowadays, Oracle) should have an option to redirect compiler output to a file. You just need to look for it hard enough :-) HS should have an option to print out all their JVM and compiler options and among them might be the one that redirects the output to a file.

Anyways, I digressed...

1) There should be src.zip in your $JAVA_HOME or %JAVA_HOME%. It contains the source code for Java Class Library.

2) Modify the System.out to redirect all output to a particular fail or simply make it insert some special symbol on which you could grep to capture the stdout and stderr. Unfortunately, I can't be more specific with this particular step, since our company's policy forbids us to inspect the contents of src.zip. I could only imagine how difficult this step would be. Maybe it is as trivial as swapping "out" with your output stream or as difficult as modifying every single print method that your app uses directly. I don't even know how many natives the System.out uses

3) Put your compiled version in a jar file.

4) Add this option to your command line: -Xbootclasspath/p:full_path_to_your_jar This will tell JVM to use your version of the class first. "P" stands for prepend.

Hopefully this helps...

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd try what @barracel noted about using System.out.println().

I don't know much about Java, but you could also write out all of your debug messages to stderr and leave stdout for the JVM. This may prevent the pollution of stdout that's apparently happening when multiple threads write to the same file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the output of JVM and your application.

- Output JVM's information to stdout
- Output your application's information to stderr, with "System.err.println()"
- Analyze the the output with your favorite tools.

So, the command line is like this:

```
$java -XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:+PrintGCDetails MainClass 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the output in non-overlapping fashion, use System.out.println. Then u can redirect to same file like this:

```
java -XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:+PrintGCDetails MainClass 1>stdout.txt 2>&1
```

This is have all the error as well as normal console outputs in file name stdout.txt

Also, if the logs have any form of thread/time information, you can simply use

```
sort -n -k 1
```

where -k 1 stand for the column in which you have thread/data(epoch) information.